# The file show more than one when export into .pdf JAVA

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hi I tried make a exporting data into .pdf, so when I view a "detail" it will show a set of data and on detail have an exporting into .pdf, when the data exporting into .pdf, the data will become a one file. But when I try to exporting the file more than one like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrKZR.jpg)

but it's not the same data it's different data from database, and I want to ask how this can happened and how to fixed this ??

this the code on bean:

```
    @PostConstruct
public void init(){

    this.setLazyMasterReportDataModel(new LazyMasterReportDataModel()); 
}

public JasperPrint exportTo() {     
    if(this.listReportMaster == null || this.listReportMaster.isEmpty()){           
        FacesMessage messageFailed = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Info","No data found");           
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(messageFailed);         
        return null;
    }
    String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/resources/report/PRPKReportPDF.jasper");     
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource  beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.listReportMaster);       
    try {           
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, null, beanCollectionDataSource);           
        return jasperPrint;         
    } catch (JRException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}   

public void exportToPdf(ActionEvent actionEvent){   
    if(this.lazyMasterReportDataModel != null){
        System.out.println("masuk exporttopdf");
        String sql = ((LazyMasterReportDataModel) this.lazyMasterReportDataModel).getSqlReportPrint();
        List<Object> listObject = ((LazyMasterReportDataModel) this.lazyMasterReportDataModel).getObjectSqlListReportPrint();
        this.listReportMaster = reportMasterPRPKController.getPRPKForReport(sql, listObject);           

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = exportTo();
        String fileName = "PRPKNew_Report".concat("_").concat(".pdf");
        if(jasperPrint != null) reportMasterPRPKController.exportToPDF(fileName, jasperPrint);
        else System.out.println("jasperprint null");
    }else{
        System.out.println("keluar exporttopdf");
        FacesMessage messageFailed = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Info","No data found");           
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(messageFailed);
    }
}
```

this code on controller

```
public void exportToPDF(String fileName, JasperPrint jasperPrint){
    try{            
        System.out.println("masuk controller exportpdf");
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=".concat(fileName));
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close(); 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();   
        System.out.println("selesai print");
    } catch (JRException | IOException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

thank's before

Answer (score 0):

The variable `listObject` in `exportToPdf` method seems to contains the list of objects passed to the report generation.

For each of these objects, **a detail band will be generated**. If you have only one detail band and 100 objects in this list, 100 band will be generated in the pdf export.

I would advise you to only provide one object to your pdf generation if you want only one detail band to be displayed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388178/jasperreport-purpose-of-the-details-band) about the detail band for more info